# Http failure response for https://api.imgur.com/3/image

Tags: angular, imgur

I am trying to upload a base 64 encoded image to imgur and it keeps failing with the error message `Http failure response for https://api.imgur.com/3/image: 403 OK`. How can I resolve it?

```
@Injectable()
export class ImgurService {
  private readonly IMGUR_UPLOAD_URL = 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image';
  private readonly IMGUR_API_KEY = '<api-key-xxxx>';

  constructor(
    private logger: NGXLogger,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {
  }

  upload(b64Image: any) {
    this.logger.debug('Handling file input');
    this.logger.debug(image);
    this.logger.debug(`Uploading picture to ${this.IMGUR_UPLOAD_URL}`);
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders ({
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.IMGUR_API_KEY}`,
      }),
    };
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', b64Image);
    formData.append('album', 'profile');
    return this.http.post<ImgurResponse>(`${this.IMGUR_UPLOAD_URL}`, formData, httpOptions);
  }
}
```

Response:

```
error:
data: {error: "The access token provided is invalid.", request: "/3/image", method: "POST"}
status: 403
success: false
__proto__: Object
headers: HttpHeaders
lazyInit: ƒ ()
lazyUpdate: null
normalizedNames: Map(0) {}
__proto__: Object
message: "Http failure response for https://api.imgur.com/3/image: 403 OK"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 403
statusText: "OK"
url: "https://api.imgur.com/3/image"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

Comment: Please provide your API response

Comment: Response added @ZarnaBorda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not setting the headers correctly:  you need to use set or append as the object is immutable.

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ${this.IMGUR_API_KEY}');
```

Most probably you can see in your browser that your auth header isn't sent.

Comment: I've done this: https://pastebin.com/YE4ZxDEm, and now get the error message https://pastebin.com/5eKidH6Z

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are passing a wrong access token.
Here is a code which worked fine for me:

```
  uploadImage(b64Image: string): Observable<Object> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.IMGUR_ACCESS_TOKEN}` });

    return this.httpClient.post(this.IMGUR_UPLOAD_URL, b64Image, { headers: headers });
  }
```

And when I give a random non-existing access token, I get 403 as well like this:
[image]

See quick sample [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2gzpza)

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to upload the image to a particular album (ie that doesnt exist yet, if it does then create it)